# Show A Single Question and Set of Answers Per Question (JS Quiz)

Tags: javascript

It's my first time making a quiz, so excuse any janky code. I just want to get it working for the time being.

All I'm looking to do is display the next set of answers in a quiz after a user selects the initial answer and presses the submit button. The answers are in their own form in the HTML.

I can display the next question on clicking the button as of now, but I can't get the current answers to disappear and then show the next set that correlates to the next question. Any suggestions?

### TL;DR

I can't get the next set of answers (next form) to show and the current set of answers to disappear after answering the first question and clicking submit. I'd like it to show a single question and set of answers per question.

I am also looking to complete this in vanilla JS as an exercise.

HTML

```
<body>

<div class="page-wrapper"> 
    <div class="user-box">

        <div class="question">
            <p id="q"> </p>
        </div>

        <div class="answer-box">
            <form id="answer1" class="answer" name="answer1">
                <input class="choice" type="radio" id="option" name="question1" value="Cleveland">Cleveland
                <input class="choice" type="radio" id="option" name="question1" value="Columbus">Columbus 
                <input class="choice" type="radio" id="option" name="question1" value="Aliiance">Alliance
                <input class="button" type="button" id="button" value="Submit" onclick="check()">
            </form>        

            <form id="answer2" class="answer" name="answer2">
                <input class="choice" type="radio" id="option" name="question2" value="Black & White">Black & White
                <input class="choice" type="radio" id="option" name="question2" value="Red & Blue">Red & Blue
                <input class="choice" type="radio" id="option" name="question2" value="Orange & Brown">Orange & Brown
                <input class="button" type="button" id="button" value="Submit" onclick="check()">
            </form>        

        <form id="answer3" class="answer" name="answer3">
                <input class="choice" type="radio" id="option" name="question3" value="One">One
                <input class="choice" type="radio" id="option" name="question3" value="Two">Two
                <input class="choice" type="radio" id="option" name="question3" value="Three">Three
                <input class="button" type="button" id="button" value="Submit" onclick="check()">
            </form>        
        </div>

        <div id="after-submit">
                <p id="number-correct"></p>

        </div>

    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
body {
background-color: #1d1e22;
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }

.page-wrapper {
 width: 100%;
 max-width: 960px;
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
 justify-content: center;
 margin: 0 auto;
 min-height: 700px; }

 .user-box {
 width: 800px;
 height: 450px;
 background-color: #393f4d;
 margin: 0 auto; }

 .question {
 width: 90%;
 color: #d4d4dc;
 text-align: center;
 padding: 10px;
 margin: 20px auto;
 font-size: 30px; }

 .answer-box {
 width: 70%;
 height: 180px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 background-color: white;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center; }

 .answers {
 width: 401px;
 text-align: center; }

 .choice {
 display: inline-block;
 margin: 0 20px; }

 .button {
 position: relative;
 top: 20px; }

 #after-submit, #wrong {
 visibility: hidden;
 text-align: center;
 color: #d4d4dc; }

 #q2, #q3 {
 display: none; }

 #answer2, #answer3 {
 display: none; }
```

JavaScript

```
    //Questions array
var questions = ["What is the capital of Ohio?", "What color is a zebra?", "How many licks does it take?"];

var displayQ = questions[Symbol.iterator]();

//Show first question on load

window.onload = function load() {
    var q = document.getElementById("q");
    q.innerHTML = questions[0];
}

function check(){
    var radios = document.getElementsByClassName("choice");
    var radioValue;
    var correct = 0;

    //Display new qusetion after click
    let nextQ = displayQ.next(); // get the next element
(nextQ.done) ? 
    [q.innerText, this.innerText, this.disabled] = ['Complete!', 'Done', true]
    :q.innerText = nextQ.value;

    //Correct answers array

    var answers = ["Columbus", "Black & White", "One"];

    //Get user radio selection value

    for (var i = 0; i < radios.length; i++){
        if (radios[i].checked) {
            radioValue = radios[i].value;
        }
    }

    //If no radio value is selected, send alert message

    if (radioValue == null){
        alert("Select an answer!");
        return
    } 

    //Check answers array against user radio value

    for (var j = 0; j <= answers.length; j++){
        if (radioValue === answers[j]){
            correct++;
            document.getElementById("after-submit").style.visibility = "visible";
            document.getElementById("number-correct").innerHTML = "You got " + correct + " correct.";
            return
        } else {
            document.getElementById("after-submit").style.visibility = "visible";
            document.getElementById("number-correct").innerHTML = "Wrong. Try agian.";
            return
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What specifically are you finding difficult?  See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I can't get the next set of answers (next form) to show and the current set of answers to disappear after answering the first question and clicking submit. 

I'd like it to show a single question and set of answers per question.

Comment: What specific /programming/ problem are you having when you try and do that?  What have you tried? What didn't work?

Comment: I've tried adding the following to the "Check answers array against user radio value" loop (last loop in the JS code)  
  
`document.getElementById("answer1").style.display = "none";
 document.getElementById("answer2").style.display  = "block";`  
  
This does work and shows the second set of answers correctly, but after that, I can’t get the third set of answers to show since there’s only one loop that checks the values against the answers.